# How to re-write an async script for Node.js in Purescript

Tags: asynchronous, functional-programming, task, ffi, purescript

I am trying to learn Purescript. A lot of the literature is focused on abstract concepts, for which the language is obviously very well suited; however, it is difficult to bring those concepts home to something familiar.

In order to better understand Purescript, and partly to challenge Purescript on a procedural task, I want to rewrite a very simple Node script written in Typescript.

The script reads some input from the command line, calls an async function that hydrates a (server-side) redux store, and then prints some data to the console.

```js
import { store } from '../server/store'
import { deep, log, red } from '../src/io'
import { isRehydrated } from './isRehydrated'

async function readRecord(dbName: string, tableName: string, recordId: string) {
  try {
    await isRehydrated()
    const result = store.getState().databases[dbName][tableName][recordId]
    deep(result)
    return 'DONE!'
  } catch (e) {
    return e
  }
}

readRecord(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], process.argv[4]).then(
  m => {
    log(m)
    process.exit()
  },
  e => {
    red(e)
    process.exit()
  }
)
```

Is there a simple way to rewrite the above script in Purescript using Purescript's FFI to call the Javascript imports and the `do` syntax to handle the async procedures?

Comment: I cannot answer your question but I can try to translate the async control flow of this highly imperative code into its functional counterpart. `isRehydrated` is a weird monadic action that doesn't receive an argument and whose return value is discarded. `readRecord` is a normal monadic action. So we need to sequence both actions, discard the first result and take only the second. There is probably a spezialized combinator I am not aware of but if you do this by hand you get something like `chain(_ => readRecord(...)) (isRehydrated())` (`Task` type with a `chain` fun in curried form assumed).

Comment: Found it: It's the `*>` combinator from Prelude (applicative section), which sequences two actions but discards the first result. In purescript it is called [`applySecond`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/3.1.0/docs/Control.Apply#v:applySecond). So I was mistaken, we don't need monad here, just applicative.

Comment: I'm not a Purescript dev but I write a lot of functional code, and there's nothing here to convert to FP. FP is all about isolating side effects, and this code is *nothing but side effects*: read from argv, read from db, write to STDOUT. There's no data processing, no transformation, no computation. This is not a good script to learn FP on... pick something that actually does something with data besides pipe it from a db to STDOUT.

Comment: @JaredSmith That's kind of the point. Just trying to get a feel for how you actually `do` (ha) things in Purescript. Apparently, I need to explore [purescript-aff](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-aff).

Comment: @RichardForrester except it isn't: again, in a strongly-typed functional language you're basically just going to be writing imperative code in an IO for that part, and for this script "that part" is all there is!

Comment: @JaredSmith I can't follow. Transforming asynchronous effects into values with an applicative/monadic type and than compose these values with the corresponding combinators is FP and nothing else than FP. The only flaw in this example is `readRecord`, because it doesn't return anything but just logs to the world.

Comment: @bob FP means different things to different people, and everything you just described is *incidental complexity*. That incidental complexity serves a purpose (namely protecting the soundness of the type system). But it's hard to see the payoff in a script like this. For another example to give the flavor of my argument, change the OP's question to the following: "HI! I'm an imperative programmer and I'd like to learn OOP by converting this node.js script to Java". Now think about what the Java version would look like i.e. god-awful. There are advantages to OOP architecture over raw imperative

Comment: ...code, but they wouldn't be shown here: transliterating (as far as is possible) the imperative code into Java classes isn't going to really teach you much about what OOP really is. And I think the same is true of FP: the heart of FP is really about immutability, declarative data transformation, referential transparency, etc. In the case of this IO-heavy script it's just overhead a la the Java 5 LoC hello world. I could see where you might disagree, but this seems a sub-optimal script for learning FP to me.

Comment: @JaredSmith You are misreading the call of the question which has nothing to do with learning FP. I am already comfortable with FP concepts. This question is about learning Purescript, Purescript’s FFI, and about how to accomplish procedural IO in Purescript with Aff and Purescript’s `do` syntax.

Comment: @RichardForrester in that case my bad, and of course disregard.

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks for the thorough reply. I think beside the points you listed, FP is also about composition of values. A value in this sense may also be one that is eventually produced by a function or an effect. That means FP allows us to compose different effects without us having to know how this very composition works under the hood. If we compose them in a functorial/applicative way, we can simply mix and match different effects and the result is still functorial/applicative. With monads we need transformers or have to write the composition manually.

Comment: @JaredSmith The point is that treating effects as first class values and composing them in various ways while this composition is always subject to the same set of rules is a big win and I believe you can learn a lot from it.

Comment: @bob IDK, sounds like a fun argument for the bar :)

Comment: @JaredSmith Yeah, let's have a beer On this subject, sounds nice..

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a work in progress.

Main.js

```js
"use strict";

exports.store = require('../../../build_server/server/store/index').store
exports.red = require('../../../build_server/src/io/console').red
exports.deep = require('../../../build_server/src/io/console').deep
exports.isRehydrated = require('../../../build_server/scripts/isRehydrated').isRehydrated
exports.path = require('ramda').path
exports.argv = process.argv
exports.exit = process.exit
```

Main.purs

```hs
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Promise (toAff, Promise)
import Data.Array (slice)
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Aff (Aff, launchAff_)
import Effect.Class (liftEffect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Foreign (Foreign)

foreign import isRehydrated :: Unit -> Promise Unit

foreign import red :: ∀ a. a -> Effect Unit

foreign import deep :: ∀ a. a -> Effect Unit

foreign import store :: { getState :: Unit -> { databases :: Foreign } }

foreign import path :: Array String -> Foreign -> Foreign

foreign import argv :: Array String

foreign import exit :: Unit -> Effect Unit

recordPath :: Array String
recordPath = slice 2 5 argv

affLog :: String -> Aff Unit
affLog msg = liftEffect $ log msg

affDeep :: ∀ a. a -> Aff Unit
affDeep m = liftEffect $ deep m

affExit :: Unit -> Aff Unit
affExit unit = liftEffect $ exit unit

isRehydratedAff :: Unit -> Aff Unit
isRehydratedAff unit = toAff (isRehydrated unit)

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  log "BEGIN EFF"
  launchAff_ do
    affLog "BEGIN AFF"
    isRehydratedAff unit
    affLog "HYDRATED"
    affDeep $ path recordPath (store.getState unit).databases
    affLog "END AFF"
    affExit unit
```

main.js

```js
require('./src/pursOut/Main/index').main()
```

At the terminal:
`node main.js`

Comment: This doesn't work because `Aff` is not the same thing as a JS Promise, so the type of `isRehydrated` import is wrong. You can import it as a [`Promise`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff-promise/2.0.1/docs/Control.Promise#t:Promise) and then use [`toAff`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-aff-promise/2.0.1/docs/Control.Promise#v:toAff) to convert it. Same with all the other functions.

Comment: After that, you'll have a problem with accessing `store`: your code is missing the whole chain of `.databases[dbName][tableName][recordId]`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Yes, I'm actually there right now, just updated the answer with aff-promise.